# How to recognize element is same which is clicked in each() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do something like this :

```
<div class="show" >Element 1</div>
<div class="show" >Element 2</div>
<div class="show" >Element 3</div>

$("div.show").click(function () { 
        $current_show = $(this);
        $("div.show").each(function () {
            if ($(this) != $current_show ) //here i want to check current element is not same
            {
              $(this).text('Write something');
            }
        });
    })
```

Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Try `$("div.show").not($(this)).each(...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for **[`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**, you can use **[`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/)** to avoid clicked element

```js
$("div.show").click(function() {
  $("div.show").not(this).text('Write something');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show">Element 1</div>
<div class="show">Element 2</div>
<div class="show">Element 3</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! you have answered not only my question but also you have reduced my code!

Comment: @Atul : glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are performing action other that setting same text then Modify `.each()` to filter current element:

```
$("div.show").not(this).each(....)
```

Otherwise you do not need to iterate over element for setting same text. Use solution provided by pranav.

Answer (score -2):

You can check for `$(this).text() != $current_show.text()` instead.